# Obj C just play mp3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, mp3

I've seen this little piece of code in at least three tutorials,when I press the button connected to the action I get:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

It says my path is null, which it is according to the console.  Any idea on what I'm missing?

```
-(IBAction) pushStart
{
    NSString *arrowSoundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Arrow.mp3" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrowSoundPath);
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:arrowSoundPath] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the '.mp3' extension from the first parameter to `-pathForResource:ofType:`. It should be `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Arrow" ofType:@"mp3"]`. The way you have it now, `-pathForResource:ofType:` is looking for a file named 'Arrow.mp3.mp3', which doesn't exist, so it is returning `nil`, which is causing your error.

Comment: Glad to help, it always seems to be the little things that slow me down the most...